# React function parameter is a Proxy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, proxy, redux

I have a function in my stateful React component and I'm getting a `Proxy` instead of what I actually expect in the function's parameters.

What is going on here? I'd expect to see `hello world` in my log, but instead I see this:

> what is this? Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: Constructor, nativeEvent:
>   Object, type: undefined, target: 196…} [[Handler]] : Object [[Target]]
>   : ResponderSyntheticEvent [[IsRevoked]] : false

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

state={}

toggleModal = (A) => {
    console.log('what is this?', A)
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { openShippingModal: !prevState.openShippingModal };
    });
   }

anotherFunctionInMyComponent = selection => {
    ///do stuff
    this.toggleModal('hello world');
  };

componentDidMount = () => {
 /* do sutff */
}  

render(){
 //return stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: I was passing `toggleModal` not only to `anotherFunctionInMyComponent` but to an `onPress` prop as well causing it to be a synthetic event. I forgot about the `onPress` prop, so the console log was actually coming from there and not `anotherFunctionInMyComponent`.  So after realizing that I was able to pass parameters to the function as expected from `onPress`.

Answer (score 2):

React uses a "Synthetic Events" system to smoother over the differences between event handling in different browsers.  You can generally treat that parameter is if it were a standard browser event object, ie, using `A.target.value` or something similar.

For more info, see the React docs on [Handling Events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) and the [SyntheticEvent API reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

Now, looking at your example, I *am* a bit confused what's going on.  Based on that snippet, yes, I'd expect that `A` would be the string "hello world".  Might be able to help more if you can show more code.

Comment: I think you are right about it being some sort of synthetic event, but `A.target.value` returns undefined and `A.type` returns 272. I added more code to help you see the structure of the component.